# Find out which desktop environment is used via shell?

Tags: unity, command-line, kde

Is there a way to find out the current desktop environment (Gnome 3 / Unity / KDE / Gnome Session Flashback) is currently used via the shell?

Answer (score 5):

Run the below command on terminal to view your desktop environment,

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

For mine,

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
Unity
```

Comment: Yes but that does not seem to differentiate between Unity and Gnome Flashback. In both cases the value is Unity.